# Swift destructuring json object

Tags: json, swift, destructor, codable

I was wondering is there the possibility to implement in `swift`, to take the attribute value and assign it to the variable with the same name as it happens with `Js`?

```swift
import Foundation

struct Car: Codable {
    var name, color, licensePlate: String
}

struct User: Codable {
    var name, surname: String
    var car: [Car]
    var number: Int = 0
}

let DB5 = Car(name: "Aston Martin DB5", color: "gray", licensePlate: "xx001xx")
let DB11 = Car(name: "Aston Martin DB11", color: "blue", licensePlate: "xx002xx")

// Encode
let user = User(name: "James", surname: "Bond", car: [DB5,DB11])

let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(user)
let json = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf16)

// Decode
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
let secondUser = try jsonDecoder.decode(User.self, from: jsonData)

// let [name, surname, car] = ...
// let {name, surname, car} = ...
// let (name, surname, car) = ...

print(secondUser, name, surname, car[0])
```

Comment: Do you mean `Tuple`?

Answer (score 1):

No, Swift does not have `struct` destructuring. It does have multiple assignment, so you could say this:

```
let (name, surname) = (secondUser.name, secondUser.surname)
```

but I wouldn't call that a big improvement.

If you need to destructure just `name` and `surname` in a lot of places, then you can make that easier by adding a computed property that returns a tuple:

```
extension User {
    var nameTuple: (String, String) { (name, surname) }
}
```

and then using it like this:

```
let (name, surname) = secondUser.nameTuple
```